# Why is "It is" incorrect in "It is because he was jealous..."?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> It is because he was jealous that John lied about his sister's prize.

I don't know why 'It is~' is wrong in the sentence.

In a text book, they say the sentence is wrong. What is the difference between

> It **is** because he was jealous that John lied about his sister's prize.

and

> It **was** because he was jealous that John lied about his sister's prize.

Comment: It's not wrong.  Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: @James K I have no idea. In a text book, they say the sentence is wrong. I asked a question because I doubted. Could you explain the difference between 'It is because he was jealous that John lied about his sister's prize.' and 'It was because he was jealous that John lied about his sister's prize.'?

Answer (score 1):

By the manner in which you phrase your question, I'm inferring that you have been asked to put the sentence in the past tense.

You might have written:

> It **was** because he was jealous that john lied about his sister's prize

The lying took place in the past and John (capital "J") was jealous at that point in time in the past (we don't know whether he is still jealous) compelling him to lie.

You might also have written:

> It **was** because he **is** jealous that john lied about his sister's prize

In this example, the implication is that John has always been jealous and remains so.

Comment: When you infer, what do you make out of you and me?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: A fair question. I felt that there was sufficient evidence to infer.

Answer (score 0):

The example could be considered "wrong" because there is no "it" to be referred to. "It" is a pronoun that refers to an object, thing, concept, event, etc. There's no real thing in the brief description that "it" is replacing or referring to.

As an editor, I could easily say that the "it" sentence is wordy, which is bad but not really "wrong." This is the simple, clear way to write the same thought:

*Because he was jealous, John lied about his sister's prize.*

Of course, "it" does refer to something: the past action, John telling a lie, and "it" can be used if we assume a question as the reason for the description:

*Why did John lie? It (his action) was (done) because he was jealous.*

Comment: The first paragraph is simply wrong. [Dummy pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun) are normal in English and some other languages.

Comment: @user8356 I reaserched it-cleft. I found something like following(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ko/%EB%AC%B8%EB%B2%95/%EC%98%81%EA%B5%AD%EC%8B%9D-%EB%AC%B8%EB%B2%95/cleft-sentences-it-was-in-june-we-got-married) for example ; It’s the parents who were protesting most.

Comment: @user8356 in addition ; It could be going home early or slacking off at work that the boss reacted to.

Comment: As to the first paragraph, some people could consider it wrong, but I do not -- use of "dummy" pronouns being common in English.